# Changing stringbuilder variable randomly

Tags: java, random, char, stringbuilder

I am trying to create a program that asks a user for a full name and then assigns that name to a `StringBuilder` variable. Then I must create an infinite loop that will change the `StringBuilder` variable randomly until the program crashes.

Does anyone know how to change a `StringBuilder` variable randomly?

I did this same project but with a string variable like this:

```
for (;;) {

  for (int i = 0; i < fullNameChar.length; i++) {
    int randomNum = generator.nextInt(133);
    fullNameChar[i] = (char) randomNum;
  }

  fullName = String.valueOf(fullNameChar);
  System.out.println(fullName);
}
```

I guess you can't convert a stringbuilder to a char, so I have to find another way to do it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why you want to write such program?

Comment: It's for an assignment. There is not real use for it.

Comment: If the assignment is to crash the system then better use String :-)

Comment: I think that is the point of the assignment! But when i wrote the same program using a string it didn't crash! :(

Answer (score 0):

Just append the random values to the string builder:

```
StringBuilder randomBuilder = new StringBuilder();
int max = 16;  // just an example for a 16 char result 
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    int randomNum = generator.nextInt(133);
    randomBuilder.append((char) randomNum));
}
System.out.println(randomBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I could do this! I appreciate your help.